# Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void System.Security.Cryptography.DSACng

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget-package

I am working on the `iOS` App in `Xamarin` in Visual Studio 2019.

My App is working perfectly on Simulator but when I am trying to `Build Solution` to deploy or debug on iPhone (registered under developer account) it's returning me this error.

```
Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void System.Security.Cryptography.DSACng::.ctor(System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey)', referenced from the method 'T Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.PkcsPalWindows::GetPrivateKey(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2,System.Boolean,System.Boolean)' in 'System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I tried many possible solutions to resolve the issue but did not succeed.

I checked all my references in the project which one is calling this `System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey` NuGet package. I tried adding other `System.Security.Cryptography.****` NuGet packages as well still received the same error.

Here is the list of references I have added to my project.

[image]

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: look at the linker settings

Comment: @Jason how I can see Linker settings? can you please explain me? and Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos

Comment: @Jason I have selected the default option `Link Framework SDKs Only`.

Comment: choose Don't Link.  If that fixes the problem, then you know its a linker issue and can use one of the other methods to exclude just the classes that you need.